# Installing conjure-up charmed Kubernetes (vSphere), error on juju deployment

Tags: juju, kubernetes

We are deploying Charmed Kubernetes on vSphere 6.7 and we are getting the following error:

```
dhiadmin@dhip1032:~/.cache/conjure-up$ tail -f conjure-up.log
2019-11-02 17:57:06,909 [DEBUG] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - telemetry.py:17 - Showing screen: Configure Applications
2019-11-02 17:57:20,935 [DEBUG] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - telemetry.py:17 - Showing screen: Configure Application
2019-11-02 17:57:21,330 [INFO] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - applicationconfigure.py:87 - Hiding options not in the whitelist: ['credentials', 'datacenter', 'datastore', 'folder', 'password', 'respool_path', 'user', 'vsphere_ip']
2019-11-02 17:58:29,432 [DEBUG] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - telemetry.py:17 - Showing screen: Configure Applications
2019-11-02 17:58:55,617 [DEBUG] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - telemetry.py:17 - Showing screen: Bootstrapping Controller
2019-11-02 17:58:55,744 [INFO] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - common.py:74 - Bootstrapping Juju controller...
2019-11-02 17:58:55,745 [DEBUG] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - telemetry.py:32 - Juju Bootstrap: Started
2019-11-02 17:58:55,745 [DEBUG] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - juju.py:213 - Bootstrapping to set region: {}
2019-11-02 17:58:55,745 [DEBUG] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - juju.py:252 - bootstrap cmd: ['/snap/bin/juju', 'bootstrap', 'cloud-vsphere-b94/DHI - Raleigh, NC (Peak 10)', 'conjure-up-cloud-vsphere-b94-523', '--default-model', 'conjure-charmed-kubernet-611', '--config', 'primary-network=VLAN_100 (10.5.10.0%2f24)', '--config', 'external-network=', '--config', 'datastore=DHI DS 004', '--config', 'image-stream=daily', '--credential', 'conjure-cloud-vsphere-b94-60e']
2019-11-02 17:58:55,758 [DEBUG] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - events.py:52 - Awaiting Bootstrapped at conjureup/controllers/juju/bootstrap/gui.py:43
2019-11-02 18:19:24,507 [ERROR] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - common.py:60 - Error bootstrapping controller: ['Creating Juju controller "conjure-up-cloud-vsphere-b94-523" on cloud-vsphere-b94/DHI - Raleigh, NC (Peak 10)', 'Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.6.9 for amd64', 'Launching controller instance(s) on cloud-vsphere-b94/DHI - Raleigh, NC (Peak 10)...', ' - creating template VM "juju-template-94ba2804af1cea22d691c99632835072b97757ea604ccc308841a6847a5373d7"', ' - streaming vmdk: 25.54% (28.4MiB/s)', ' - streaming vmdk: 62.40% (15.5MiB/s)', ' - streaming vmdk: 85.48% (26.9MiB/s)', ' - cloning template', ' - VM cloned', ' - extending disk to 8.0GiB', ' - powering on', ' - juju-f1cff1-0 (arch=amd64 mem=3.5G) ', 'Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance', 'Fetching Juju GUI 2.15.0', 'Waiting for address', 'Attempting to connect to 10.5.10.111:22', 'Attempting to connect to fe80::250:56ff:fe0d:7df4:22', 'ERROR failed to bootstrap model: waited for 20m0s without being able to connect: ssh: symbol lookup error: /snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_vfork, version GLIBC_PRIVATE']
2019-11-02 18:19:24,509 [DEBUG] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - events.py:52 - Setting Error at conjureup/events.py:149
2019-11-02 18:19:24,509 [ERROR] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - events.py:161 - Unhandled exception in <Task finished coro=<BaseBootstrapController.run() done, defined at /snap/conjure-up/1056/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/controllers/juju/bootstrap/common.py:15> exception=BootstrapError('Unable to bootstrap (cloud type: vsphere)',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/conjure-up/1056/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/controllers/juju/bootstrap/common.py", line 21, in run
    await self.do_bootstrap()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/1056/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/controllers/juju/bootstrap/common.py", line 65, in do_bootstrap
    app.provider.cloud_type))
conjureup.errors.BootstrapError: Unable to bootstrap (cloud type: vsphere)
2019-11-02 18:19:24,521 [DEBUG] conjure-up/charmed-kubernetes - __init__.py:27 - Showing dialog for exception: Unable to bootstrap (cloud type: vsphere)
```

Answer (score 0):

A 20minute timeout was triggered, but the error message is far from ideal. To deploy to vSphere, Juju needs to download a VM image from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/.

If you're still interested in evaluating Charmed Kubernetes on your vSphere instance, there's still hope! Use Juju directly, rather than via conjure-up:

```
juju add-cloud vsphere
juju bootstrap
```

The `add-cloud` command will take you through an interactive prompt so that you're able to add in the vSphere details. It's not quite as polished as conjure-up, but won't get blocked by the timeout problem.